# How to move Flyout Menu button for Desktop .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

How to move Flyout Menu button for Desktop[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tjfZ.png)

Comment: Hi, check this video of how to customize the flyout! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHmLYP-YNpk  Anyway i quite don't understand what you want to move with that picrute? the FlyoutIcon? please edit or try to be more specific so we can help you! Hope it helps

Comment: Hi yes me need to move FlyoutIcon

Comment: maybe he needs a RTL version

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official [doc](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/Fundamentals/Shell) and relevant [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/Fundamentals/Shell).

I test the above sample via windows platform. And here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uak7P.jpg). The location of FlyoutIcon should be the official default location. Just like the location of FlyoutIcon on Android platform.